# Why is my textbox loaded text disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a textbox ACLBox that I want to display a string upon initialization of the user interface. Upon initializing, the string flashes for a second then disappears. Why?

Here's the xaml code for the textbox:

```
     <Window x:Class="Funnel.ACL"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Funnel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ACL Configuration" Height="300" Width="560" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Closing="exitACL"
    Background="LightGray" Name="ACLConfiguration">

<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid x:Name="FunnelGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ShowGridLines="False">

            <!--Defining Grid-->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label x:Name="Config" 
                   Content="ACL CONFIGURATION" 
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="9" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Blue"
                   FontWeight="Heavy"
                   FontSize="16">
            </Label>
            <CheckBox x:Name="aclCheckbox" 
                      FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                      Content="ACL ON"
                      Foreground="Blue"
                      FontWeight="Heavy"
                      FontSize="16"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.RowSpan="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Checked="ACL_Check"
                      Unchecked="ACL_Unchecked"
                      />

            <Label x:Name="AddIPAddress" Content="Add IP Address" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="90" Height="30"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddIPTextBox1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="AddIPTextBox1_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddIPTextBox2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="AddIPTextBox2_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddIPTextBox3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="AddIPTextBox3_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddIPTextBox4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="AddIPTextBox4_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="AddErrorBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding AddErrorText}"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddButton" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="50" Click="addClick" FontSize="12" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Background="LightSteelBlue"  VerticalAlignment="Top">ADD</Button>

            <Label x:Name="DelIPAddress" Content="Remove IP Address" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Width="120" Height="30"></Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="DeleteIPTextBox1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="DeleteIPTextBox1_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="DeleteIPTextBox2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="DeleteIPTextBox2_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="DeleteIPTextBox3" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="DeleteIPTextBox3_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="DeleteIPTextBox4" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Width="35" Height="20" TextChanged="DeleteIPTextBox4_TextChanged"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="DelErrorBox" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding DelErrorText}"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="50" Click="deleteClick" FontSize="12" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Background="LightSteelBlue"  VerticalAlignment="Top">DELETE</Button>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteAllButton" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="25" Width="80" Click="deleteAllClick" FontSize="12" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Background="LightSteelBlue"  VerticalAlignment="Top">REMOVE ALL</Button>

            <Label x:Name="ACLBoxLabel" Content="Access Control List" Foreground="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>

            <TextBox x:Name="ACLBox"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Grid.Column="6"
                 Grid.RowSpan="4"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="220" 
                 Height="150"
                 FontSize="14"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Text="{Binding ACLBoxText}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 TextAlignment="Center" /> 
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's the C# code for the string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Funnel
{
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for ACL.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class ACL : Window
     {
         AclManager _manage = new AclManager();
         FileController _controller = new FileController();
         string addStr1;
         string addStr2;
         string addStr3;
         string addStr4;
         bool addError;
    string delStr1;
    string delStr2;
    string delStr3;
    string delStr4;
    bool delError;
    public string aclText;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ACL()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if(FunnelGlobals.accessControlList)
        {
            aclCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
        }

        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }

    private void exitACL(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        _controller.writeAclFile();
    }

    private void ACL_Check(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FunnelGlobals.accessControlList = true;
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }

    private void ACL_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FunnelGlobals.accessControlList = false;
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }

    private void AddIPTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddErrorBox.Text = "";
        AddIPTextBox1.Text = AddIPTextBox1.Text;
        addStr1 = AddIPTextBox1.Text;
        if(!_manage.isDigit(addStr1))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            AddErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            AddErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
            addError = true;
        }
       else
        {
            addError = false;
        }
        ACLBox.Text = _manage.getAclList();
    }
    private void AddIPTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddErrorBox.Text = "";
        AddIPTextBox2.Text = AddIPTextBox2.Text;
        addStr2 = AddIPTextBox2.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(addStr2))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            AddErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            AddErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
        }
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }
    private void AddIPTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddErrorBox.Text = "";
        AddIPTextBox3.Text = AddIPTextBox3.Text;
        addStr3 = AddIPTextBox3.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(addStr3))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            AddErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            AddErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
        }
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }
    private void AddIPTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddErrorBox.Text = "";
        AddIPTextBox4.Text = AddIPTextBox4.Text;
        addStr4 = AddIPTextBox4.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(addStr4))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            AddErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            AddErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
        }
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }
    private void addClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String addStr = addStr1 + "." + addStr2 + "." + addStr3 + "." + addStr4;
        if(_manage.isLegit(addStr))
        {
            FunnelGlobals.aclIPs.Add(addStr);
        }
        if(addError)
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            AddErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            AddErrorBox.Text = "Fix Invalid Characters before Adding";
        }
        else
        {
            aclText = _manage.getAclList();
        }

    }

    private void DeleteIPTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelErrorBox.Text = "";
        DeleteIPTextBox1.Text = DeleteIPTextBox1.Text;
        delStr1 = DeleteIPTextBox1.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(delStr1))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            DelErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            DelErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
            delError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            delError = false;
        }
    }

    private void DeleteIPTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelErrorBox.Text = "";
        DeleteIPTextBox2.Text = DeleteIPTextBox2.Text;
        delStr2 = DeleteIPTextBox2.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(delStr2))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            DelErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            DelErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
            delError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            delError = false;
        }
    }

    private void DeleteIPTextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelErrorBox.Text = "";
        DeleteIPTextBox3.Text = DeleteIPTextBox3.Text;
        delStr3 = DeleteIPTextBox3.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(delStr3))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            DelErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            DelErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
            delError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            delError = false;
        }
    }

    private void DeleteIPTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelErrorBox.Text = "";
        DeleteIPTextBox4.Text = DeleteIPTextBox4.Text;
        delStr4 = DeleteIPTextBox4.Text;
        if (!_manage.isDigit(delStr4))
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            DelErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            DelErrorBox.Text = "Character NOT Valid";
            delError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            delError = false;
        }
    }

    private void deleteClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String delStr = delStr1 + "." + delStr2 + "." + delStr3 + "." + delStr4;
        FunnelGlobals.aclIPs.Remove(delStr);

        if (delError)
        {
            Color foreColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("red");
            Brush errBrush = new SolidColorBrush(foreColor);
            DelErrorBox.Foreground = errBrush;
            DelErrorBox.Text = "Fix Invalid Characters before Removing";
        }
        else
        {
            aclText = _manage.getAclList();  
        }
    }

    private void deleteAllClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FunnelGlobals.aclIPs.Clear();
        aclText = _manage.getAclList();
    }

    private void ACLBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ACLBox.Text = _manage.getAclList();
    }
    public string ACLBoxText
    {
        get { return aclText; }
        set { aclText = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ACLBoxText"); }
    }

    private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `ACLBoxText` is null or empty, right? Why did you bind a viewmodel property *and* initialize `ACLBox.Text` in the Loaded event? Don't step on yourself like that. Bind `ACLBoxText` (which you already did), and initialize `ACLBoxText` to initialize what's in the text box. If you're binding a viewmodel property, just use the property. Get rid of that Loaded handler. That's probably what's wrong; try it and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Set the `Text` property only through `binding` or only through code behind. When you set the `property` in code behind, the `binding` gets broken.

Comment: I want the text to be from a list that the user can update...add or delete from at will. When the user goes to the list configuration I want the textbox to display this list. It flashes into the textbox for a second then goes away. Then if you add to it the list appears and stays. I'm doing both the exact same way except now I've added some code from the comments below. The code disappears still. I do not see where in the code it could be overwritten. Using Visual Studio I looked through every implementation of ACLBox.Text and it's always set to _manage.getAclList();

Answer (score 0):

As Ed Plunkett has already mentioned, you should use your `ACLBoxText` backing variable instead of resetting the control value.

Something like this will work:

```
private void ACLBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ACLBoxText = _manage.getAclList();
}
```

Unfortunately, the view doesn't know about changes to backing properties unless you tell it that something changed.  You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
private string _aclBoxText;

public string ACLBoxText {
    get { return _aclBoxText; }
    set {
        _aclBoxText = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ACLBoxText");
    }
}

protected void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Something like that will work if OP turns the view into a fake viewmodel *and* sets `this.DataContext = this;`, though it's not a great way to do things. But I think you need to find out what (if anything) `ACLBoxText` actually is first. If there's a viewmodel, OP certainly shouldn't discard it and start over like this.

Comment: I added the notification and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

> Upon initializing, the string flashes for a second then disappears. Why?

Probably because you are "overwriting" the value of the ACLBoxText source property, which is initially displayed in the TextBlock, when you set the Text property of the TextBlock in your Loaded event handler.

If the TextBlock is empty once the UI has been loaded you should make sure that the _manage.getAclList() method returns the string that you expect it to return. You could temporarily try to assign the Text property to a "static" value:

```
private void ACLBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ACLBox.Text = "TEXT";
}
```

But I agree that it doesn't make much sense to first bind the Text property of the TextBlock to a source property in the XAML markup and then handle the Loaded event of the same TextBlock and set its Text property to a new value in this event handler. But I guess you have your reasons...

Note that binding that you define in the XAML markup will get reset when you programmatically set the Text property in your Loaded handler though.

So you should either don't bind the Text property in the XAML markup, or don't handle the Loaded event and set the Text property programmatically. It's one or the other but not both.

Comment: If I had a static string value then it appears and disappears as well. I do not see any code that would overwrite the value.

Comment: What about the code in your Loaded event? This overwrites the initial value.

Comment: The loaded event is the same value as the initial value. Without the loaded event nothing appears in the box until you add another IP address. Then the entire list plus the new IP appears in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. This is my first C# project and first time ever using Xaml (wpf) so I misunderstood binding. I bound the text like I did in the primary gui. The text is never getting triggered within this gui so I could only see the text flash because of loaded but then the text binding reset the textbox to nothing. When I changed my text to not be bound then everything works as I wanted. Lesson learned. Binding is only needed when accessing a textbox from within .cs files. It is not needed within xaml.cs. Since my text would only ever be triggered by xaml.cs just setting text the usual way(ie textbox.text = "whatever") does what I need. Thank you everyone for your help. I understand binding much, much better now. Java does things differently. :)