# WPF TextBox Error Message Visible and Doesn't Disappears When Text Written in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Error Message already showing when I build and run the code in TextBox and doesn't disappear when text is written in TextBox
I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2017
I am using MaterialDesignThemes Version **2.6.0**

I have used the TextBox code form the DemoApp

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="NameTextBox"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Name"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Width="200">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding
            Path="Name"
            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <rules:NotEmptyValidationRule
                    ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                    xmlns:rules="clr-namespace:Spirit.Domain" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This is My NotEmptyValidationRule defined in Spirit.Domain namespace which is a copy of validation rules form the demo app

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
        ? new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required.")
        : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
}
```

I have also included a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQZwP.gif)

Please provide a demo or details steps for solving the error

Comment: Hello!Welcome to SO. Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366087/why-is-my-textbox-loaded-text-disappearing

Comment: How is your Name property defined? Does it raise PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Thanks @Gleb problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add **PropertyChanged** event on the Name property used in the binding..